# design issue when too many derived classes are needed

Tags: entity-framework, inheritance, design-patterns, software-design, derived-class

I am trying to build a badge system that is similar to `StackOverflow` in my entity-framework code-first application.

I will have around 10 badges in total and each type of badge has its own properties. I am thinking to have base class `Badge` and derive the other classes from the base class.

For example, there will be **Sprinkle** badge and it will be automatically assigned to the user if his post is liked 3 times or more. So, I will have `Sprinkle` class with additional property `NumberOfLikes` (so that it can be updated later). However, in the database table, there will be only one record for this class. Isn't this weird?

I will have 10 classes like this, and there will be only single record for their corresponding table in the database. I have to have separate classes for each to be able to configure their unique properties.

Is my design choice a poor one?

Comment: Nope, not weird at all. I'm not familiar with intricate database performance but I doubt the number of tables has an impact on performance. Having a de-normalized table will be a lot more negative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may consider to differentiate between the business rule of the badge, that is coded in the derived badge class and the bookkeeping of earned badges of a user. I see no need to have this rule classes be entity framework classes and to store them in the database if it does not have any parameters you want to change frequently. You could store this parameters in other configuration stores (eg. exe.config) or similiar or hardcode it. The (perhaps only one) instance of this classes are purely to execute the business rule. See them as services (DDD) or perhaps strategy pattern or (for evaluation) visitor pattern. They could just be created (perhaps per IoC/Di container that automatically creates all derivations) without storing/loading in the database.
On the other hand you have to bookkeep which user earned which badge (it could be a performance hit to calculate this new on every request). Here it makes sense to have a class that is stored in the database (1:n) and stores the list of badges a user received. So after every change (new post, new like, whatever) or from time to time (nightly run) you run through your badge rule classes and every badge the user does not already have (or if it is possible to loose a batch you take all) is executed for this user to check if it applies. If yes, the marker is created that the user earned the badge.

Comment: Thanks for these great answer. I wonder if you still recommend this, if I need to configure these badges per different user groups?

Comment: I think in this case they should be stored in a database. Every User Group should have its own set (1:n) of "ActiveBadgeRules" or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, you may store in your database the user, his post and the number of likes. The Sprinkle badge could be a result of some business rules (is your post (or user) Sprinkle compatible) and may not be stored in your database?

In other worlds, the Sprinkle badge is a way to see a post (or a user) having more than 3 likes?

Maybe this rules could be stored in your database and parametrized?